# PHP simple HTML DOM parser: make it loop until no error

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I had an app called GrabUrTime, it's a timetable viewing utility that get its timetables from another site, my university's webspace. Every 2am I run a script that scrapes all the timetables using the parser and dump it into my database.

But today the uni's server isn't running well and my script keeps on giving me error 500 on uni's server, making the script cannot continue to run. It's periodic, not always. However I tried a few times and it just occurs randomly, no pattern at all.

Hence I want to make my script to handle the error and make it loop until it gets the data.

```
function grabtable($intakecode, $week) {
$html = file_get_html("http://webspace.apiit.edu.my/schedule/intakeview_intake.jsp?Intake1=".$intakecode."&Week=" . $week);
$dumb = $html->find('table[border=1] tr');
$thatarray = array();
        for ($i=1; $i < sizeof($dumb);++$i){
        $arow = $html->find('table[border=1] tr', $i);
         $date = $arow->find('td font', 0)->innertext;
         $time = $arow->find('td font', 1)->innertext;
        $room = $arow->find('td font', 2)->innertext;
        $loca = $arow->find('td font', 3)->innertext;
         $modu = $arow->find('td font', 4)->innertext;
         $lect = $arow->find('td font', 5)->innertext;
        $anarray = array($date, $time, $room, $loca, $modu, $lect);
        $thatarray[$i] = $anarray;

        //echo "arraylol";
    }
    //echo serialize($tablearray)."<br/>";
    $html->clear();
    return $thatarray;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
function getHttpCode($url)
{
    $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    $page=curl_exec($ch);

    //echo curl_error($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) 
    {
        // YOUR CODE
    }
else
{
    // What you want to do should it fail
    // perhaps this will serve you better as while loop, e.g.
    // while($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) { ... }
}
```

**usage**

```
 getHttpCode($url);
```

It might not plug neatly into your code as it is but I'm sure it can help with a little re-factoring to suit your existing code structure.

Comment: So I have to rewrite the whole code since I am using the HTML DOM parser :P

Comment: @AnonozChong , I don't think so, can you not just do something like along the lines of passing the `grabtable` function another parameter which will be the httpcode. Then in the function itself check if the httpcode is correct, if not, re-run the function or something similar to that?

Comment: oh... I missed something in the manual, sorry bout that, I will try your code. Any idea on how to make it an infinite loop until I get the html?

Comment: hmm, maybe creating a new function will work, inside the new function, use the httpcode function to return the status. then check the status using an if statement. if it passes call your original scraping function, if it fails call the new function again, e.g.: `function x() { $status = getHttpCode($url); if($status >=200 && $status <300){ grabtable($intakecode, $week) } else {x()}` this is just off the top of my head so will probably need a few tweaks. if you get stuck you can always open a new question for the new problem you run into. You just need to get $intakecode and $week in there.

Comment: Oh great idea... why didn't I think of that... thanks alot
But it will become 2 different requests right... FYI the script has 500++ timetables to go through, without any problem it takes 10 minutes to complete.

Comment: I see, I can't think of a better way at the moment but if you get it to work first I think you'll be able to improve it from there. If not you could ask here and I'm sure there's another Stack Exchange website is more open to code refactoring questions, can't remember the exact name of it just now though.

Comment: Got it working... but used a hefty 1200 seconds... I cannot submit my solution though, Stack banned me from doing that